# Cocoa - Programmatically stretching an NSView vertically, moving everything after it down

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, resize, nsview

I have three NSViews stacked on each other, and I want to be able to programmatically resize the middle one to stretch it vertically, moving the bottom one down by the same amount that the middle one stretches.

Here is an ASCII picture:

```
|--------------|
|      1       |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|      2       |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|      3       |
|--------------|
```

So basically I want to be able to stretch NSView 2 vertically so that the resulting picture would look like this:

```
|--------------|
|      1       |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|              |
|      2       |
|              |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|      3       |
|--------------|
```

What is the correct way to go about doing this? Thanks!

---

Edit: Here's a follow-up question...

How can I go from this:

```
|--------------|
|      1       |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|      2       |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|     2.5      |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|      3       |
|--------------|
```

To this:

```
|--------------|
|      1       |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|              |
|      2       |
|              |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|              |
|     2.5      |
|              |
|--------------|

|--------------|
|      3       |
|--------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with autoresizing mask.

You can set the autoresizing mask programatically with

```
- (void)setAutoresizingMask:(NSUInteger)mask
```

Or in Interface builder.

In IB, the first view's autorisizing mask would be

[image]

The second :

[image]

The third :

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly. As a follow-up question, what if I want another NSView inserted after 2 and before 3 (let's call it 2.5), such that both 2 and 2.5 expand vertically together as the main window is resized?

Comment: I've added ASCII images to demonstrate the follow-up question.

Comment: The 2.5 view's autoresizing mask should be the same as the second one... Be sure to set the frame correctly!

Comment: @gcamp: What do you mean by setting the frame correctly? It's not exactly working for me, so what things should I check about the frame?

Comment: @gcamp: The exact problem is: 2 and 2.5 are overlapping when I stretch the window.

Comment: I just checked that out and you're right. That doesn't seems to be possible with autoresizing mask... You should probably use a 'NSSplitView' as the center view...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either need an `NSSplitView` or [CHLayoutManager](https://github.com/davedelong/CHLayoutManager).

Comment: Thanks for the link to CHLayoutManager! It looks like it can be really useful.